# richtextbox diplay not proper unicode in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, unicode

I used richtextbox in vb2005, I have read Unicode data from database.

it shows not correct because it space in Unicode character.

Why richtextbox include space in the Unicode character ?

any ideas how to remove space in Unicode when display Unicode in richtextbox ?

Coding:

```
If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        RichTextBox1.Rtf = dt.Rows(0)(0).ToString
End If
```

Comment: RTF is not Unicode.  Invented long before Unicode was started, it uses plain ASCII encoding with markup to enable charsets.  The question is woefully poorly documented, the simple explanation is that the string just contains a space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple replace command.

```
Dim StringWithoutSpaces As String
StringWithoutSpaces = dt.Rows(0)(0).ToString.Replace(" ","")
```